# While doing "Excel to pdf conversion " via Python I am getting error

Tags: python, excel, exception, automation

Error is : (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)

```
xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(cwdx+"\\Temp\\Excel\\Temp_excel"+str(i)+".xlsx")
ws = books.Worksheets[0]
ws.Visible = 1
rpt_path=cwdx+'\Pdfs\\'+str(i)+'_report_card.pdf'
print("Report_"+str(i)+"_Printed")
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,rpt_path )
```

at line : ws = books.Worksheets[0]

It was working properly just few minutes ago

Comment: Can you share the full traceback please?

Comment: Pandas tag is redundant, removed.